# VS2005 - Multiple files with same name in the same project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file, visual-studio-2005

Is there a way to add multiple files having the same name to a single Visual Studio 2005 project ? I want my files to have the same name as my classes.
Namespaces avoid naming conflicts, but the problem remains for file names.
I could prefix each file with the namespace "path" but that would get ugly. Is there a way to use folders (i'm not talking about filters) with VS 2005 ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Of course you can use folders. You can have one base source folder, and then a sub-folder for each namespace. That's how I arrange all my source. However, I don't know how VS will handle the object files generated though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is - just put the file into the desired folders on disk.

Unfortuantely, that's not all there is to it. You also have to change the file's object location (or name) - because by default, VS dumps all object files from a project into one directory, regardless of where they were on disk originally. The object file location for a source file is accessed through that source file's properties. Go to `Properties > C/C++ > Output Files > Object File Name`.